# Help with jEuclid in Java

Tags: java, math, tex

I have to display some math equations in Java application. I've downloaded jEuclid, but I have no idea how to use it and do not seem to be able to find any good tutorial. I have to display fractions in the form

> (P+R*sqrt(D))/Q

At the moment I am using `jTextArea` and the output is basically

> P: num, R: num, D: num, Q: num

How can represent this fraction with jEuclid? In latex I would do

```
\frac{...}{...}
```

but how to do that with jEuclid?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand (from reading the website), JEuclid is a program which converts presentional MathML to graphics. Thus you'll have to write your input in [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), either in text form or with some XML API, and then feed this to JEuclid.

For your example, it would look like this (adapted from the example in Wikipeda):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow>
        <mi>P</mi>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mn>R</mn>
        <mo>⁢<!-- &InvisibleTimes; --></mo>
        <msqrt>
          <mi>Q</mi>
        </msqrt>
      </mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mn>Q</mn>
      </mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Here is the screenshot of this MathML document in JEuclids MathViewer:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: JEuclid can also directly display MathML in an image form without needing an intermediate image file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Java program to transform MathML into image:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.MutableLayoutContext;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.context.LayoutContextImpl;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.context.Parameter;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.converter.Converter;

public class MathMLToImage{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Converter converter = Converter.getInstance();
        File inputFile = new File("D:\\TEMP\\mathml.xml");
        File outputFile = new File("D:\\TEMP\\image.jpg"); 
        //params to mention the size of image
        MutableLayoutContext params = new LayoutContextImpl(
                LayoutContextImpl.getDefaultLayoutContext());
        params.setParameter(Parameter.MATHSIZE, 50f);

        converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile , "image/jpeg", params);
    }

}
```

You can use this image output to display in your application.